# How to create a smaller array from a larger array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, where-clause

I have a large 4D data set and need to create a smaller 4D array from it.  I am fairly new to python and am use to IDL or matlab.  I read in my values then using the where function I find the index numbers I need for each dimension from smaller 1D arrays.  I am trying to create a new array from these index numbers but I keep getting the shape mismatch error (can not be broacast to a single shape.

```
import numpy as n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Scientific.IO.NetCDF as S

file=S.NetCDFFile('wspd.mon.mean.nc',mode='r') #Opening File
Lat=file.variables['lat'].getValue()     # Reading in the latitude variables, 73
Lon=file.variables['lon'].getValue()     # Reading in the longitude variables, 144
Level=file.variables['level'].getValue() # Reading in the levels, 17 of them
Defaulttime=file.variables['time'].getValue()   # Reading in the time, hrs since 1-1-1
Defaultwindspeed=file.variables['wspd'].getValue()     # Reading in the windspeed(time, level, lat, lon)

Time=n.arange(len(Defaulttime))/12.+1948  #Creates time array into readable years with 12 months
goodtime=n.where((Time>=1948)&(Time<2013)) #Creates a time array for the years that I want, 1948-2012, since 2013 only has until October, I will not be using that data.
goodlat=n.where((Lat>=35)&(Lat<=50))  #Latitudes where the rockies and plains are in the US
plainslon=n.where((Lon>=275)&(Lon<=285))

Windspeedsplains=Defaultwindspeed[goodtime,:,goodlat,plainslon]
```

The error below is generated by the line above (last line of code).

```
>>>ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Comment: i doubt anyone will be able to help you with a question that looks like this.  The least you could do is figure out which line is actually failing

Comment: Is `Defaultwindspeed` actually 4D? Use `Defaultwindspeed.shape` or `Defaultwindspeed.ndim` to check...

Comment: @atomh33ls it must be, otherwise the error would be `too many indices`. I think the problem is in the shapes of `goodtime`, `goodlat`, and `plainslon`.  @Cwilliams, what do you get if you print `goodtime.shape, goodlat.shape, plainslon.shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that the lengths of each of your index (`where`) arrays is going to be different, and so the shape of your output array is ambiguous, hence the error.  To force the broadcasting to the proper shape, you'll have to reshape your arrays to broadcast to a proper shape, something like this:

```
Windspeedsplains = Defaultwindspeed[goodtime[0][:, None, None, None],:,goodlat[0][:,None],plainslon[0]]
```

The `[0]` are there becuase `np.where(a)` returns a tuple of length `a.ndim` with each element of the tuple being an array of indices that fit your condition.  I'm assuming all of your boolean arrays are 1d, so all the `where` outputs are going to be tuples of length 1, so we just want the one array from it, hence `[0]`.

After we get the array, we want to reshape it to match the shape that you want your output array to have.  Presumable, the shape your output should have is `(goodtime.size, Defaultwindspeed.shape[1], goodlat.size, plainslon.size)`, so you must make each of your index arrays have the shape that matches the axis along which the output array should vary for that variable.  For example, for `goodtime`, you want `Windspeedplains` to vary with respect to time along axis `0` of `4` axes.  So, `goodtime` itself must also vary only along axis `0` of four axes, so you force the index array to have shape `(N, 1, 1, 1)` which is what `[:, None, None, None]` does.

So, you could make the above line more readable with:

```
goodtime = n.where((Time>=1948)&(Time<2013))[0][:, None, None, None]
goodlat = n.where((Lat>=35)&(Lat<=50))[0][:, None]
plainslon = n.where((Lon>=275)&(Lon<=285))[0]

Windspeedsplains=Defaultwindspeed[goodtime, :, goodlat, plainslon]
```

Or actually, since you can index with the boolean arrays directly:

```
goodtime = ((Time>=1948)&(Time<2013))[:, None, None, None]
goodlat = ((Lat>=35)&(Lat<=50))[:, None]
plainslon = ((Lon>=275)&(Lon<=285))

Windspeedsplains=Defaultwindspeed[goodtime, :, goodlat, plainslon]
```

Here is a somewhat simpler example:

```
In [52]: a = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)

In [53]: a
Out[53]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])

In [54]: mask0 = np.where(a[:,0,0] >= 9)

In [55]: mask0
Out[55]: (array([1, 2]),)   # <-- this is the length 1 tuple I was talking about. we want the array inside.

In [56]: mask1 = np.where(a[0,:,0]%2 == 0)

In [57]: mask1
Out[57]: (array([0, 2]),)

In [62]: mask2 = np.where(a[0,0,:] < 1)

In [63]: mask2
Out[63]: (array([0]),)

In [67]: b = a[mask0[0][:, None, None], mask1[0][:, None], mask2[0]]

In [68]: b
Out[68]: 
array([[[ 9],
        [15]],

       [[18],
        [24]]])

In [69]: b.shape
Out[69]: (2, 2, 1)
```